# What is the Default Font Foreground for Windows Phone Controls

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, wptoolkit

I am trying to match the default font of the `ToggleSwitch` Header property from the WPToolkit to a `TextBlock`. I've noticed that the default font of the `ToggleSwitch` header does not math the `TextBlock`. What can I use to apply the some text foreground to a `TextBlock`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the existing Style template `Setter` for that property to see what it's using and just apply the same to the Style template for the other? So if for example we look at the template shared on MSDN for the [default Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709931.aspx) it shows on line 7;

`<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />`

So you could either set it to that via the default template for `TextBlock` in the Resource Dictionary or say for example all your instances within a user control like;

```
<Blah.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
     <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
   </Style>
</Blah.Resources>
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE NOTE**: I apparently grabbed the default template of the windows store app Toggle instead of the Windows phone but the same question applies of checking whats in the default template and matching it to the other.

Comment: I understand. I do not believe the `ContentControlThemeFontFamily` is part of Windows Phone 8. But in referencing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003979/toggleswitch-color-styling the bottom of the first style listed contains a line stating `<ContentControl x:Name="Header" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="#467CCD" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" .../>` that contains a `Foreground` which I'll have to apply to my `TextBox` and check.

Comment: If in doubt (and you're using either vs2012 or Blend) just right-click either of those objects, choose "Edit Template" and then choose either "Edit Current" or "Edit a Copy" and that will expose your Style template and you can check/change your values quick and painless, or just find the templates in your ResourceDictionary and edit them directly.... I think its something like *Styles.xaml for the phones.

Comment: Choosing the edit template helped. The `ToggleSwitch` header foreground is `PhoneSubtleBrush` in case this helps anyone else out later.